# Enzyme Mount/Shallow once on before hook on Mocha

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I have component which I mount/shallow every test cases, and I find this redundant. Is mounting it once on `before` hook a good idea? Or are there issues that I might encounter later especially if I'm going to set states or props on my component?

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount,shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import ScheduleApp from '../src/components/schedule-app.jsx';
import ScheduleForm from '../src/components/schedule-form.jsx';
import ScheduleTable from '../src/components/schedule-result-table.jsx';

describe('<ScheduleApp/>', function() {
  describe('Initial Mount', function() {
    let wrapper;

    before(function() {
      wrapper = mount(<ScheduleApp />);
    });

    it('contains 1 <ScheduleForm/> component', function() {
      expect(wrapper.find(ScheduleForm)).to.have.length(1);
    });

    it('contains 1 <ScheduleTable/> component', function() {
      expect(wrapper.find(ScheduleTable)).to.have.length(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not going to test **Schedule App** with different props, you don't need to mount it for each case.

You also don't need to import child components (ScheduleForm and ScheduleTable) in order to tell enzyme find them. [Enzyme finds child components by their display name](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.md).

You can refactor the code above as

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import ScheduleApp from '../src/components/schedule-app.jsx';

describe('<ScheduleApp/>', function() {
  describe('Initial Mount', function() {
    const wrapper = mount(<ScheduleApp />);

    it('contains 1 <ScheduleForm /> component', function() {
      expect(wrapper.find('ScheduleForm')).to.have.length(1);
    });

    it('contains 1 <ScheduleTable /> component', function() {
      expect(wrapper.find('ScheduleTable')).to.have.length(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Just what I thought. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: By the way, if we can get rid of the `before` hook, by doing it the way you did it then what are the other use cases for `before` with `ReactJS`?

Comment: I haven't actually used hooks like before, beforeEach and afterEach while testing React components.

However, these hooks are useful when using mocking libraries like [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock). [Here's an example](https://github.com/LaborWorks/bilgi-shuttle-web/blob/master/app/redux/modules/nodes/index.test.ts#L65-L67)